# Cause sqlite to sleep in execution

Tags: sql, sqlite, sleep

Is there a similar **SQL**-expression to sleep like MS SQL `WAITFOR` for sqlite?

Alternatively, is there a way to make a sqlite **SQL**-query run for a long time without adding a lot of rows to the database?

It's for a test so it needs to be done running a query using the db driver.

Comment: What language are you accessing SQLite from?

Comment: Pick one... I need SQL code.

Answer (score 10):

SQLite has no built-in function for this, but in most languages, it is possible to create a user-defined function:

```py
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_function("sleep", 1, time.sleep)
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT sleep(1.23)")
```

Comment: Interesting but it will block in python rather than sqlite, no?

Comment: The `sleep` function is called by SQLite, so it blocks both.